# I applied a code to show a text on mouseover. However, On small screen font size decreased. But i want size remain same and adjust height/width only

Tags: jquery, css

Below is my code. i tried to increase the font-size but it doesn't work. I tried to increase the mouse x and y co-ordinate but it also doesn't work.

```
$('.tooltipp').css('cursor','pointer');
$('.tooltipp').hover(function(){
var comment = $(this).attr('comment');
$(this).data('tipText', comment).removeAttr('comment');
$('<p class="HoverBlock"></p>')
.css('display','none')
.css('position','absolute')
.css('border','1px solid #42bcb9')
.css('background-color','#FFFFFF')
.css('border-radius','5px')
.css('padding','8px')
.css('color','black')   
.css('box-shadow','1px 1px 10px #42bcb9')
.css('width','auto')
.html(comment)
.css('font-size','21em !important')
.appendTo('body')
.fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
$(this).attr('comment', $(this).data('tipText'));
    $('.HoverBlock').remove();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
var mousex = e.pageX + 23; //Get X coordinates
    var mousey = e.pageY + 12; //Get Y coordinates              
    var blockWidth = $(".HoverBlock").width();      
    var docWidth = $(window).width()
if ( (docWidth - mousex) < 325)
        $('.HoverBlock').css({ top: mousey, left: e.pageX-300});
    else
        $('.HoverBlock').css({ top: mousey, left: mousex});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you remove `!important`. I've just tried it and it does work.

If you do need to use `!important`, then you have to use it this way:

```
.css('font-size','21em', 'important')
```